# The best way to include all controllers in yii2 rest urlmanager

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am using Yii2 rest service. I want to include all my controllers in rest url manager. Now I have config main.php like below:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'usera'],
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'userb'],
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'userc'],
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'userd'],
        ],
    ],
```

Can I use something like this, so I do not have to include every controller in the config file?

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => '*'],
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use two ways:
1) Use array in controller property

```
'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['user', 'usera', 'userb'....]],

        ],
```

But you must set all controllers.

2) Create new class and extends from `yii\rest\UrlRule`.

```
namespace app\rest;
class UrlRuleCustom extends UrlRule {
  $path = '@app/controllers';
  public function init()
  {
    $d = dir(Yii::getAlias($this->path));
    $arr = [];
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
       if (strpos($entry, 'Controller.php') !== false) {
          $arr[] = lcfirst(str_replace(['Controller.php'], '', $entry));
       }
    }

    $this->controller = $arr;    


     parent::init();
  }
}
```

And in urlManager:

```
'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'app\rest\UrlRuleCustom', 'path' => '@app/controllers'],
        ],
```

But I don't know did work `Yii::getAlias` in `UrlRuleCustom`. If didn't work set instead of absolute path or relative.